# SQL. Display every bikes that are black

Tags: sql, inner-join

I'm brand new at SQL. I'm trying to display all the bikes that are colored black. I keep getting errors such as not unique tables/alias: Product. What am I missing?

```
SELECT Vendor.VendorID, Product.ProductID
FROM Product
INNER JOIN Product ON Vendor.VendorID = Product.ProductID
WHERE product.ProductColor = "Black";
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Why join the same table? If you do something like this you need to give these tables different names.

Comment: Show what you tried. Say what you expected & why. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table.

Comment: You must be getting an error message, and it will be a faq, and you can of course expect it to be a beginner's faq. Before considering posting please read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask], other [help] links, hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Vendor.VendorID, Product.ProductID
FROM Product
INNER JOIN Product -- <-- this is the problem
ON Vendor.VendorID = Product.ProductID
WHERE product.ProductColor = "Black";
```

You meant to put `Vendor` there. Your server is complaining that you joined Product to itself but didn't tell it which of the two uses of "Product" to apply the where condition to.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. You do not have `vendor` table but you have mentioned that table column on join. Also, You should always use `alias` for the tables when you use `join` as it gives more readability.

```
SELECT v.VendorID, p.ProductID
FROM Product p
INNER JOIN Vendor v
ON v.VendorID = p.ProductID
WHERE p.ProductColor = 'Black';
```